# Explanations on np.delete to remove all a last block of 2 columns

Tags: python, numpy, delete-row

I need to understand if, with the below using of `np.delete`, we perform a removing of all block of 2 columns and `len(pk)-1` rows **OR** if we just delete the last line composed of 2 columns `hk` and `pk` indexed by `len(pk)-1`.

```
# Save all the fiducial power spectrums.
aaa = len(zrange)
while aaa >= 0:
    if aaa == len(zrange):
        kh, pk = np.loadtxt(
            "test_matterpower_" + str(aaa) + ".dat",
            usecols=(
                0,
                1,
            ),
            unpack=True,
        )
    elif aaa > 0:
        kh1, pk1 = np.loadtxt(
            "test_matterpower_" + str(aaa) + ".dat",
            usecols=(
                0,
                1,
            ),
            unpack=True,
        )
        kh = np.vstack((kh, kh1))
        pk = np.vstack((pk, pk1))
    else:
        kh1, pk1 = np.loadtxt(
            "test_matterpower_" + str(len(zrange) + 1) + ".dat",
            usecols=(
                0,
                1,
            ),
            unpack=True,
        )
        kh = np.vstack((kh, kh1))
        pk = np.vstack((pk, pk1))
    aaa = aaa - 1

kh = np.delete(kh, len(kh) - 1, axis=0)
pk = np.delete(pk, len(pk) - 1, axis=0)
with open("pkkh_seq", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(pk) + str(kh))
outP = open(fold_path_fid[0] + "/Pks8sqRatio_ist_LogSplineInterpPk.dat", "w")
```

Indeed, I would like to remove all the last block, i.e remove the last `len(pk)-1` rows (composed of 2 columns).

Is the syntax correct here to perform this ?

Comment: you have been on this site for a while now, you should know how to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and to **never use images for code**

Comment: Youl should be able test the alternatives with small examples in an interactive `numpy` session.  With `np.delete` you specify which rows to the remove.  In your example you specify just one row, not a range.  Use a slice to specify a range.  But if you are deleting rows at the end, you could instead just select what you want to keep, e.g. `kn[:n]`.

Comment: Repeated `kh = np.vstack((kh, kh1))` is a poor idea; it's slow because each time requires a full copy.  It's better to collect the `alist.append(kn1)` in a list, and do one `vstack` at the end.  And if you have a list, you could use list delete or slicing to remove selected rows first.

Comment: @hpaulj . Thanks for your answer, this is what I was expected, I am sure right now that I have to use a slice or equivalent to remove an entire block of rows x 2 columns. Best regards